# How to trace the dependency between Test / compile and Compile / compile in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm learning about the internal of sbt a little.
What i am after at this point, is the dependency between Test / compile and Compile / compile.  I'm trying to figure out where and how that connection is defined.  That is, why Test  / compile, triggers Compile / compile.  Is there a way to trace that dependency?

I have tried to inspect the command with inspect tree and actual, but it is verbose and there is a lot, and ultimately could not trace that link. Could anyone help me with  figuring out how to trace that link ?